# Why the sequence of parameter may impact tar's execution?

Tags: tar

Example:

```
$> tar -vxf something.tar
(normal output)
...

$> tar -xfv something.tar

tar: v: Cannot open: No such file or directory
tar: Error is not recoverable: exiting now
```

This is absurd, is it a bug or oversight in tar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's nothing particularly absurd. `tar` supports [multiple option styles](https://www.gnu.org/software/tar/manual/tar.html#SEC35), and the `-f` option expects to be followed by the filename. If you use the old option style, `tar` is a bit more lenient:

```
$ tar xfv foo.tar
foo
$ tar -xfv foo.tar
tar: v: Cannot open: No such file or directory
tar: Error is not recoverable: exiting now
```